# How can I check if a file exists in a tar archive with Python?

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

I would like to verify the existence of a given file in a tar archive with Python before I get it as a file-like object. I've tried it with [`isreg()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarInfo.isreg), but probably I do something wrong.

**How can I check if a file exists in a tar archive with Python?**

I tried

```
import tarfile


tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar", "w")
tar.add("test1.txt")
tar.add("test2.txt")
tar.add("test3.py")
tar.close()

tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar", "r")
tai = tar.tarinfo(name="test3.py")
print(tai.isreg())
print(tai.size())
tar.close()
```

Probably *tai* is wrong. In fact `tai.size()` is always 0.

Answer (score 6):

If you really need to check, then you can test for membership using the [`getnames`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames) method and the `in` operator:

```
>>> import tarfile
>>> tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar", "w")
>>> "sample.tar" in tar.getnames()
True
```

However, I think that in Python (and dealing with file systems in general), catching exceptions are preferred. It's better to attempt to read and catch an exception because things can always happen between checking a file's existence and reading it later.

```
>>> try:
...     tar.getmember('contents.txt')
... except KeyError:
...     pass
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `getnames()`?

```
tar = tarfile.open('sample.tar','r')
if 'test3.py' in tar.getnames():
    print 'test3.py is in sample.tar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tar.getnames()` and the `in` operator to do it:

```
$ touch a.txt
$ tar cvf a.tar a.txt
$ python
>>> names = tarfile.open('a.tar').getnames()
>>> 'a.txt' in names
True
>>> 'b.txt' in names
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This matches even if the tar file has the filename in a subdirectory, and uses normcase to mimic the filename case handling of the current OS (e.g. on Windows, searching for “readme.txt” should match “README.TXT” inside the tar file).

```
def filename_in_tar(filename, atarfile):
    filename= os.path.normcase(filename)
    return any(
        filename == os.path.normcase(os.path.basename(tfn))
        for tfn in atarfile.getnames())
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the files inside a tar archive you can use either the [getmembers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getmembers) or the [getnames()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames) methods of a `TarFile` object. Then, to extract them, you can use either the [extract()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extract) or [extractfile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) methods.

For example:

```
# Archive: "sample.tar" >> Content: "test1.txt", ...
filename = "test1.txt"
with tarfile.open("sample.tar", "r") as tar:
    if filename in tar.getnames():
        file = tar.extractfile(filename).read()
```

But take in mind that the names returned are actually relative file paths. Meaning that, if the *"test1.txt"* file you're looking for is stored in a *"test"* sub-directory inside the tar archive, than its `TarInfo.name` will actually be *"test/test1.txt"*.

So, going back to the previous example, you should do something like:

```
# Archive: "sample.tar" >> Content: "test", "test/test1.txt", ...
filename = "test1.txt"
with tarfile.open("sample.tar", "r") as tar:
    for name in tar.getnames():
        if name.endswith(filename):
            file = tar.extractfile(name).read()
```

Finally, to test it, you can use `@patch()` to mock the `tarfile.open()`.

For example:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestTarfile(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('myfile.tarfile.open')
    def test_tarfile_open(self, mock_open):
        mock_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value.getnames.return_value = [
            "test",
            "test/test1.txt"
        ]
```

**NOTE:** As stated in the documentation, the support for using `TarFile` objects as context managers in *with* statements was added starting from version 3.2.